# Comparing the binary representation of DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, data-structures

I have a `DateTime` represented as long (8 bytes), that came from `DateTime.ToBinary()`, let's call it `dateTimeBin`. Is there an optimal way of dropping the Time information (I only care for the date) so I can compare it to a start of day? Lets say we have this sample value as a start of day.

```
DateTime startOfDay = new DateTime(2020,3,4,0,0,0);
long startOfDayBin = startOfDay.ToBinary();
```

I obviously know I can always convert to a `DateTime` object then get the date component. However, this operation is going to happen billions of times and every little performance tweak helps.

- Is there an efficient way of extracting the Date info of `dateTimeBin` without converting it to `DateTime`? Or any arithmetic operation on the `long` that will return the date only?
- Is there a way to match `startOfDay` (or `startOfDayBin`) and `dateTimeBin` if they have the same date components?
- Is there a way to see `if (dateTimeBin >= startOfDayBin)`, I don't think the `long` comparison is valid.

N.B. all the dates are UTC

Comment: I've never seen a `GetBinary` method on a `DateTime` in c# - you sure thats not a custom extension? Or did you mean [`ToBinary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tobinary?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @Jamiec good spot, I meant `ToBinary`, I fixed it.

Comment: Ok good. The problem you have is that the binary is not just a number (Ticks) it also encodes the `Kind` property too. I suspect what you're trying to do is possible with the `Ticks` alone, but the binary representation is specifically to be able to derialize/deserialize correctly

Comment: YOu could always look at the source for [DateTime](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,df6b1eba7461813b) and operations like `ToBinary` and `Date` which a) shows you the maths and b) may make you wonder whether the JIT will just inline everything anyway and you should just use those methods.

Comment: There is no "date part" or "time part" since it's just a number of ticks since the beginning of the epoch. Bit bashing doesn't help there. You should first establish this is an actual bottleneck; if it is, consider using a different on-wire format that splits date and time. There is little reason to assume you're going to write code that's much faster than what `DateTime` does on its own.

Comment: If all the dates are UTC then why not use `Ticks` instead?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I did a benchmark and converting every long back to DateTime for the sake of comparison added 2 minutes of execution time. 'Bit bashing' helps if you are building a custom database not doing business programming and processing terabytes of records. However, splitting the Date and Time on saving is a good idea. Thank you.

Comment: @juharr good suggestion, thanks.

Comment: You can extract date and time, if we assume `ToBinary` just returns `Ticks` for UTC dates (you can check source code to see if such assumption is correct, I don't know). Then you have ticks and to extract time - just do `yourBinaryThing  % (24 * 60 * 60 * 10_000_000)` (10 million ticks in second, that much ticks in a day). To remove time and get only date, just do `yourBinaryThing  - (yourBinaryThing  % (24 * 60 * 60 * 10_000_000))` and so on.

Comment: (and from the above it should be obvious that regular comparision of `binary` dates is valid if they represent ticks).

Comment: @Evk saving and loading from Ticks solves all the problems given that this is using UTC only. Would you like to contribute a full answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working only with UTC dates - makes sense to use `DateTime.Ticks` instead of `DateTime.ToBinary`, because former has relatively clear meaning - number of ticks since epoch, just like the unix time, the only difference is unix time interval is second and not tick (where tick is 1/10.000.000 of a second), and epoch is midnight January 1st of 0001 year and not year 1970. While `ToBinary` only promises that you can restore original `DateTime` value back and that's it.

With ticks it's easy to extract time and date. To extract time, you need to remainder of division of ticks by number of ticks in a full day, so

```
long binTicks = myDateTime.Ticks;
long ticksInDay = 24L * 60 * 60 * 10_000_000;
long time = binTicks % ticksInDay;
```

You can then use convert that to `TimeSpan`:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks(time);
```

for convenience, or use as is. The same with extracting only date: just substract time

```
long date = binTicks - (binTicks % ticksInDay);
```

Regular comparision (`dateTimeBin >= startOfDayBin`) in also valid for tick values.