# Pandas datetime values messed up after saving df to excel and then reading back into a df

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

```
jan_21=[datetime(2021,1,1) + timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(5)]


jan_21
    
[datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 1, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 2, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 3, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 4, 0)]

prices = np.random.randint(1,100,size=(5,))

prices

[46 23 13 26 52]

df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':jan_21, 'price':prices})

df

             datetime  price
0 2021-01-01 00:00:00     83
1 2021-01-01 01:00:00     60
2 2021-01-01 02:00:00     29
3 2021-01-01 03:00:00     97
4 2021-01-01 04:00:00     67
```

All good so far, this is how I expected the dataframe and datetime values to be displayed. The problem comes when I save the dataframe to an excel file and then read it back into a dataframe, the datetime values get messed up.

```
df.to_excel('price_data.xlsx', index=False)

new_df = pd.read_excel('price_data.xlsx')

new_df

                      datetime  price
0   2021-01-01 00:00:00.000000  83
1   2021-01-01 00:59:59.999999  60
2   2021-01-01 02:00:00.000001  29
3   2021-01-01 03:00:00.000000  97
4   2021-01-01 03:59:59.999999  67
```

I'd like `df == new_df` to evaluate to `True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Against the backdrop of the likely cause of the issue (see sophros' answer), what you could do to - superficiously - circumvent the problem is converting the cells of `df["datetime"]` to strings before producing the excel file and then converting the strings to datetime again, after `new_df` has been created:

```
df["datetime"] = df["datetime"].dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
df.to_excel('price_data.xlsx', index=False)

new_df = pd.read_excel('price_data.xlsx')
new_df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(new_df["datetime"], format="%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i just tried and it works!

Comment: @PruthviAmin Glad it works! If that is the case, you should accept the answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the difference in time part of `00:59:59.999999` and  `02:00:00.000001` and `03:59:59.999999` is most likely related to a slightly different binary representation of date/time types in [Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/981865/6573902) and [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) or [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html).

The time is frequently stored as a float but the difference is when is the 0-th time (e.g. year 1 AC or 1970 - as in Linux; [good explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64701686/6573902)). Therefore, the conversion may loose some least significant parts of the date/time and there is not much you can do about it but round it up or using [approximate comparisons as with any float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python).